# How to give an event handler access to member data?

Tags: c++, .net, delegates

```
         myWebClient->DownloadProgressChanged += gcnew DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler( &Form1::DownloadProgressCallback );
```

gives the error:

> 1>.\Form1.cpp(26) : error C3352: 'void Form1::DownloadProgressCallback(System::Object ^,System::Net::DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs ^)' : the specified function does not match the delegate type 'void (System::Object ^,System::Net::DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs ^)'

The documentation uses a static non member function as this delegate parameter, but I want to update a progress bar member of the `Form1` class. What am I doing wrong here?

I am using .NET 2.0 so please keep the language as antiquidated as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the object to the delegate constructor.

```
gcnew DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler( this, &Form1::DownloadProgressCallback );
```

Answer (score 2):

The delegate for a member function would be declared (within the form):

```
 myWebClient->DownloadProgressChanged += gcnew DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(this,  &Form1::DownloadProgressCallback );
```

Basically, the first argument is the object one which the member function is defined.  In this case, `this` should work.